# Visualizing large panel data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, panel, longitudinal

I have about 200,000 different subjects in my study. I have a different number of observations for each subject (ranging from 1 to 200, but most are below 10). I'd like to visualize the change over time for these subjects, for a specific variable. Is there any visualization or package in R useful to visualize large panel data?

Comment: I am using ggplot2 together with plotly. It produces nice interactive plot, but is very slow with too many data ... gap <- ggplot(df, aes(x = variable_x, y = variable_y, color = as.factor(label))) + 
  geom_point(aes(frame =time,shape = as.factor(variable1) ,size = variable2)); 
ggplotly(gap)